# My React component is re-rendering, cannot figure out why

Tags: reactjs, firebase, use-state

I'm building a React App with Firebase and my component is constantly re-rendering.
I tried some things that didn't work (because they couldn't work, like settig useState inside the callback).
This is the code, please help!

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const [input, setInput] = useState('');

const msgRef = ref(db, 'messages');
onValue(msgRef, snapshot => {
  const msg = snapshot.val();
  if (Object.values(msg) != messages) {
    setMessages(Object.values(msg));
  }
})
```

Also, I know it is re-rendering because of this code beacuse I console.logged it.

Comment: Also, I know this is probably not a good question, but I need help because I just don't understand this.

Comment: On render you are calling OnValue function wich may be calling setMessages always, wich causes another render, and so on

Comment: Any side-effects should be placed inside a `useEffect`. Any call to setters will still trigger a re-render, but at least, it won't be an infinite loop!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your read the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), you see the following

> This method is triggered **once when the listener is attached** and again every time the data, including children, changes

When your component renders the following is happening

1. Attach listener
2. Fire listener method straight away
3. `setMessages` is called
4. Because `setMessages` is being called, the component performs another render, which results in
5. A listener being attached again
6. The listener method being fired straight away
7. `setMessages` is called

... And so on

The body of a functional component should not contain side effects (that is code that does something *other than produce the render output*). To trigger a side effect when a component first renders, you need to use a [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). It's going to look something like this:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onValue(msgRef, snapshot => {
      const msgRef = ref(db, 'messages');
      const msg = snapshot.val();
      if (Object.values(msg) != messages) {
        setMessages(Object.values(msg));
      }
    })
    
    // A function that is returned from the useEffect callback 
    // will be called when the component unmounts. 
    // This is the correct way to remove the listener
    // when you don't need it any more
    return unsubscribe

  // The empty array passed into the second argument will result in
  // this function *only ever being called once*
  }, [])

  // rest of component code
}
```